# Unnecessary space after 10th number in numbered list

Tags: microsoft-word

I created a numbered list. But there is unnecessary space after 10th.

[image: Unnecessary space before 10]

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

### You want to change the tab stop and associated hanging indent in the *style* associated with that level in your numbering.

I recommend doing  this in the **Define New MultiLevel List dialog** rather than through the tab settings. *This is true even for a single-level list!*

[image: Screenshot of menu]

[image: Screenshot of multilevel list dialog]

**You can set both the left indent and the tab for your list in this dialog.**

See:

- [Number Alignment](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/NumberAlignment2007.htm) by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill
- [How to set up outline numbering](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html) by Word MVP Shauna Kelly
- [Setting Tabs](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/SettingTabs.htm) by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill

Comment: If you don't see the part to the right, ensure you clicked on "more" on the bottom left.

Answer (score 3):

My solution:

1. Right-click on any number in the numbered list (all numbers should then be highlighted in gray)
2. Click “Adjust List Indents…”
3. See "Follow number with:"
4. If “Tab character” is selected, change it to either “Space” or "Nothing" -- whichever suits your fancy

Answer (score 1):

Please also try to insert the cursor after number 10., right click > Adjust List Indents, check the Text Indents and Follow number with.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your tabs are set wrongly. Single digits are tabbing the the first stop, 2 digit are jumping to the second.

See how the first tab stop crosses the periods on the 2-digit numbers?

[image]

How to set Tab Stops - [MS KB - Set tab stops and paragraph indents in Microsoft Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/set-tab-stops-and-paragraph-indents-in-microsoft-word-34361115-2b5a-9fcc-2d34-9d7c9e007b71)